# Is there any difference between calling function in functionName.prototype.methodName() and funObject.methodName()?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I create a function constructor like this

```
function ClassName() {
}
```

and then I write methods for this constructor like this

```
ClassName.prototype.a = function() {
console.log("A Executed")
}
```

Now I have two ways to call this newly created method `a`

1. `ClassName.prototype.a()`
2. `var obj = new ClassName()
   obj.a()`

both of the above ways give me the exactly same output i.e,

> A Executed

but somewhere I feel these must be some differences which I am not aware of. Is there any difference in these two ways. Somebody, please throw some light

Comment: If it's a static method, one that doesn't use `this`, there's no difference. The difference is all about accessing the current instance, i.e. `this`.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is function context

```js
function ClassName(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

ClassName.prototype.a = function() {
  console.log("A Executed", this.name, this === obj, this === ClassName.prototype)
}

var obj = new ClassName('test')
obj.a();
ClassName.prototype.a()
```