# Nodejs invoking a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a student new to learning Node.js. Why would the console.log give me undefined? I expect it would print out 'Hello World!' instead. Where am I wrong?

Thanks!

```
function Greetr() {
    this.greeting = 'Hello World!';
}


Greetr.prototype.greet = function() {
    console.log(this.greeting);
}

Greetr.prototype.greet();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any difference between calling function in functionName.prototype.methodName() and funObject.methodName()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44517936/is-there-any-difference-between-calling-function-in-functionname-prototype-metho)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you access your greet via your prototype. `this` in that case is not your object as you expect. You can see what is `this`, by logging it.

```js
function Greetr() {
    this.greeting = 'Hello World!';
}

Greetr.prototype.greet = function() {
   console.log(this);
}

Greetr.prototype.greet();
```

As you see, `this` refers to your `prototype object`, which doesn't have any property with name `greeting`, so it log `undefined`.

To get the desired result you need first to create an `object`, then call your `greet` function via that `object`

```js
function Greetr() {
   this.greeting = 'Hello World!';
}


Greetr.prototype.greet = function() {
   console.log(this.greeting);
}

var greetr = new Greetr();
greetr.greet();
```